# Adding numbering to subsubsections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am using the [masters-doctoral-thesis] (https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)
template for writing my paper. I am trying to add numbering to subsubsection-level headers.

[image]

[image]

The subsubsections are there, but they aren't numbered.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The document class you employ is based on the `book` document class, which sets `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}`, meaning that sectioning units up to `subsection`, but no lower, are numbered.

To enable numbering of subsubsection-level headers, you need to insert the instruction

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

in the preamble of your document.

Comment: ty vm @Mico it worked very fine . for the same way i also added this line \setcounter{tocdepth}{4} for numbering it inside the content list

Comment: @Ahmed.AI - Thanks for the checkmark. :-) The document class you employ sets `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`, which overrides the default of the underlying `book` class. Unless your document contains `\paragraph` commands -- a detail about which you've provided no information so far -- it shouldn't be necessary to run `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}`.